# Can a vampire charm a blind person?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, conditions, vision-and-light, charmed

Can a vampire charm a blind person?

The wording of the [vampire's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire) Charm action has me a bit confused on whether a blind person either gets no saving throw from it or can't be charmed at all like this.

Here is the exact description:

> ***Charm.*** The vampire targets one humanoid it can see within 30 feet of it. If the target can see the vampire, the target must succeed on a DC 17 Wisdom saving throw against this magic or be charmed by the vampire.

Of course, this question is also relevant in case the vampire is invisible or otherwise hidden in plain sight from a target with normal eyesight.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Interestingly, it does seem to be the case that a Vampire *cannot* charm a Blind target, or any creature that cannot see the Vampire

You have correctly quoted the [Vampire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire) Charm ability as stating:

> The vampire targets one humanoid it can see within 30 feet of it. **If the target can see the vampire**, the target must succeed on a DC 17 Wisdom saving throw against this magic or be charmed by the vampire [...]

Compare this to the [*charm person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) spell which has no such requirement:

> You attempt to charm a humanoid you can see within range. It must make a Wisdom saving throw, and does so with advantage if you or your companions are fighting it [...]

And now compare it to the [Eyes of Charming](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/eyes-of-charming) which do have this same restriction:

> These crystal lenses fit over the eyes. They have 3 charges. While wearing them, you can expend 1 charge as an action to cast the charm person spell (save DC 13) on a humanoid within 30 feet of you, **provided that you and the target can see each other** [...]

This shows that there do at least exist charming effects that also require two-way line-of-sight.

---

It should be noted that being under the [blinded condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded) *does* indeed make the creature unable to see:

> **A blinded creature can't see** and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight.

Comment: How do you feel about the fact that the Vampire may even charm when in animal form? Usually there could be an explanation regarding how much sense it would make to roleplay it, but in this case it is really weird that a Vampire bat could charm a person while in normal shape it cannot charm a blind person? I imagine invisible Vampires charming the pcs

Comment: @techorix That sounds like a related but different question you could ask on this site (comments aren't really means to expend your original question).

Comment: Sometimes I like the quotes of the rules-lawyery bits of the source books like "a blinded creature can't see". Cpt. Obvious reporting for duty.

Comment: @techorix It's not weird though. Bats aren't blind so the vampire can still see the target and if the target can see the "bat" then the rule is working as intended.

Comment: @techorix most likely the charm is not "beauty-based" as you seem to be assuming, but rather based on the "mesmerizing gaze" of the vampire, which need not be affected by the animal form.

Comment: Yeah I guess there are two kinds of enchantments. Gazing ones like charm and the ones like suggestion where you have to be able to hear the person. Makes sense

Comment: You sure about this reading of the rules? Because to me it seems to suggest that if a creature cannot see the vampire, it simply doesn't get a saving throw, not that it can't be targetted.

Comment: @Vlaz Not really, no... You're not taking the whole sentence. The clauses are: "If it can see... it must succeed... or be charmed." By not considering all three clauses, you're introducing a double-negative and inverting the meaning.